# Error with Withdrawing on remix-ethereum-compiler.io into Metamask Account

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, metamask, contract-deployment

I was using the https://remix-ethereum-compiler.io but I cannot withdraw my ethereum that was transfer with metamask.

It is possible to recover via withdraw? Or any available app to do it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to recover the ETH you already sent. That contract is a common scam, only the scammer can withdraw it. For the future, don't trust code that promises easy gains, and learn first how ethereum works so you'll notice that frontrun bots like these don't make sense.

Comment: The official site for the Remix IDE is https://remix.ethereum.org/. The most recent version is 0.42.

Comment: But if the scammer can do it , so anyone with knowledge of the code can do it too, right ?

Comment: @MhiKea No, that's not true. A contract has full control what it is posible to do. For example it can restrict function access to some addresses, it can only withdraw to a hardcoded address, etc.